# How to build an image on Docker?

Tags: docker

I'm following tutorial on this [link](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app) and up to this step as shown below image[image]

On the above image I believe 'friendlyhello' is the name of the image however I wasn't able to build successfully. Please refer to below.

[image]

So what've I tried was instead of assigning a name I replaced `firstimage` with the path of the directory

```
docker build /Developer/Docker
```

And what I got is an image without any title as below

[image]

May I know the reason behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the build command, you are ignoring the `.` at the end of the command. This arugment is the path to directory containing the dockerfile.

```
docker build -t friendlyhello .
```

In this case you are specifying that the Dockerfile is in the current directory of the terminal.

Comment: Sorry that I've overlooked it as I'm new to UNIX environment. Thanks a lot for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Either you posted incomplete line of your command, or you have not used . at the end:

```
docker build -t friendlyhello .
```

The dot at the end marks the directory with Dockerfile.

You can find some examples [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage).

Comment: Sorry that I've overlooked it as I'm new to UNIX environment. Thanks a lot for pointing it out